# for input type="number" how to set default value to 0

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

For a textbox that accept numbers as shown below, how can the default value be set to 0?

```
<input name="smtpPort" type="number" id="smtpPort" size="30" maxlength="50" class="input-full" tabindex="4" value="{{model.PortNumber}}">
```

Though the value in DB is null, it still shows 0 in textbox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to default the value to 0 in the field when the DB has a NULL value ?

Comment: You want to fix the value in the DB, or fix the value displayed in the textbox?

Answer (score 50):

HTML attribute to set a default value is `value`:

```
<input type="number" value="1">
```

You're setting this default value to `null`, and nothing (in HTML) can change it to zero (or anything else).
You must fix the value in your database, or in your template engine (something like `{{model.PortNumber || 0}}`).

At least, you can force your field to be filled with `required` attribute:

```
<input type="number" required value="">
```

Comment: Thank a lot everyone. This worked for me.      <input name="smtpPort" type="number" id="smtpPort" size="30" maxlength="50" class="input-full" tabindex="4" value="{{model.PortNumber}}  || 0">

Answer (score 5):

```
<input name="smtpPort" type="number" id="smtpPort" size="30" maxlength="50" class="input-full" tabindex="4" value="{{model.PortNumber || 0}}">
```

I assume you're using AngularJS.

Comment: Any idea on how to do in react js?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal any solution in react js?

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam : Yes, Trying to set in a state with initial value something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201501/how-to-set-default-value-to-numeric-input-field-in-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

The correct way should be to fix the value before sending to template. However, if you still insist on doing it in frontend, you can also try using `||` operator in your AngularJS frontend.

```
<input name="smtpPort" type="number" id="smtpPort" size="30" maxlength="50" class="input-full" tabindex="4" value="{{model.PortNumber || 0}}">
```