# how to set default value to numeric input field in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a sample reactjs form, which has a input number field as shown below:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" 
  min="1" 
  step="1"
  value={this.state.userCount}
  onChange={this.handleUserCountChange}
/>
```

How to set the default value to 5 for the numeric field?

Comment: You didn't attach your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set the initial state of `userCount` to 5 check the docs :
https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#an-interactive-component

Answer (score 1):

in your constructor you can set the state.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    userCount: 5
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the value of that numeric input to the component state:

**this.state.userCount**

When this form is initially rendered, it will populate the input with the value stored in this.state.userCount.

Like other posters have mentioned, you just have to set the the initial state:

> **React createClass syntax:**
>
> ```
> var TestForm = React.createClass({
>   getInitialState() {
>     return {
>       userCount: 5
>     };
>   },
> });
> ```
>
> **ES6/ES2015 class syntax:**
>
> ```
> class TestForm extends React.Component {
>  constructor(props) {
>    super(props);
>    this.state = {
>     userCount: 5
>    };
>  }
> }
> ```